# Get Javascript Confirm result from VB.Net Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I have an ASP.NET application specifically VB.NET as the back-end. I have already written a JavaScript to ask the user whether they want to save or not and if no, operation should be canceled. Furthermore before Data is saved into the Database, I have another dialog to display another Java Script Confirm pop up in case  a name matches and existing name in the database. If the client clicks on cancel then operation should cease but if yes then the rest of code should executed. IF IT WERE Vb.Net only it would have been this way:

`if msgbox("There is an existing staff name like this in the system, Do you want to proceed?,vbyesNo + vbquestion)<>vbyes then exit sub`

Please note I want to achieve all these at code behind. Any help?

Comment: Just cancel the AJAX request or however you're sending data if they click cancel? You can't control javascript in your backend

Comment: You'll need to display a new button on the screen and handle that button on the back end as a "I'm very sure I want to save".

Comment: Yep Jaxi that is a nice idea, cancelling the Ajax Request but how do I get the value of what the user chooses in the first place? That is how do I get to know that the user has selected ok or cancel? this is my challenge because once I get those values the rest can be handled.

Comment: if I was using onclientclick event, that would have been easy but here is the case a code has to run on the server side for this procedure call to be called.

Comment: Secondly, the Lotus, my challenge here is how to get the value of yes or no. Or do you mean I should create two separate codes and assign one to search for exiting data whilst the other handles the execution of the query? I tried this code but cannot get the result. Can someone help me out with streamlining this code? : <br/>  <pre> Public Sub conmsg(ByVal smgs As String)
        Dim msg As String
        msg = "<script language='javascript'>"
        msg += "confirm('" & sMessage & "');"
        msg += "</script>"
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(msg)<code>

Comment: I think I would just go with a modal pop up(which I wanted to avoid) that would do the job I want.

Comment: We need to see more of your code to see what you're doing, the js and code behind. It's a bit confusing right now. Also look into [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/e89f1306-e43d-49ae-a66a-e18b71007666).